# Website returning 403 when POSTing URL ending with questionmark

Tags: php, apache, centos

I have been having a unique issue where whenever I POST a URL ending in a `?`, the page will return a 403 error.

Here is my example code:

**page.php:**

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

POST to page.php:

- `https://google.com/?ref=123` returns 200 `Array([url] => https://google.com/?ref=123)`
- `https://google.com/?ref=123?` returns 403
- `http ? abc` returns 200 `Array([url] => http ? abc)`
- `http ?` returns 403
- `abcd ?` returns 200 `Array([url] => abcd ?)`

Why is it if my URL contains `http` and ends in a question mark, it will throw a 403 error?

I am running CentOS Linux V7, PHP v7.2.10, and Apache V2.4.6

Comment: 403 is the HTTP code for Forbidden. If your code is not returning that then Apache may be doing so because of configuration data in `.htaccess`, or in the system configuration files. There's nothing in what you've posted that would indicate which.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I removed everything in my .htaccess file and it still returned 403 error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured out my problem:

In `/usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com.error.log` there were lines that said:

> [Mon May 22 17:42:53.522519 2023] [:error] [pid 886:tid 140380883953###] [client IP:15555] [client IP] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Match of "endsWith /modules/paypal/express_checkout/payment.php" against "REQUEST_FILENAME" required. [file "/usr/local/apache/modsecurity-cwaf/rules/02_Global_Generic.conf"] [line "29"] [id "211120"] [rev "12"] [msg "COMODO WAF: Remote File Inclusion Attack||example.com|F|2"] [data "Matched Data: https? found within REQUEST_FILENAME: /path/to/file.php"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "CWAF"] [tag "Generic"] [hostname "example.com"] [uri "/path/to/file.php"] [unique_id "ZGvh3ZWCyBfOi8SV7cODxwAAAAI"], referer: https://example.com/path/to/file.php

In `/usr/local/apache/modsecurity-cwaf/rules/02_Global_Generic.conf` I commented out the matching line